# TF2 crashing during map transition

Tags: team-fortress-2, technical-issues

I was playing TF2 last night and I managed to get in to game fine. When the match ended and a new map was loaded, the game crashed for a minute but when it restarted, everything on the screen was white, the sound was looping and the text was displayed as small black blocks.

I closed down and restarted the game, entered a new game on a new server but the same thing happened when transitioning from one map to another. This time, everything on the map went multi-coloured and the text, again, displayed as blocks. This time, however, I was able to play.

I've never had a problem before. When I started up Steam last night there was a update for the game which I think may be causing my problems. Is this an issue with the game itself or the update? Or is it something to do with my computer, i.e the graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to [verify the integrity of your files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)?

I find that doing this step solves 90% of my load/crashing problems with most steam games.

Comment: Between that and deleting clientregistry.blob, I'd say only 1% of steam problems I've hit have required further investigation

Comment: Thank you. Verifying the files seems to have done the trick